# Chronometer font doesn't change in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, chronometer

I want to change the font of my chronometer in android.I have set my default font to be a custom font . The font seems to be applied every where except the chronometer. I have also tried setting `android:fontFamily="@font/myfont"` but it didn't work. Though the font appears to be applied in the preview window, but it doesn't change when i run my app on my device.

Any idea to get over it ?

Here's my code:

```xml
<Chronometer
            android:fontFamily="@font/linotte_semibold"
            android:id="@+id/audio_player_chronometer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/frame_layout"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />
```

Comment: I searched a solution for you and find out that to do this people always create a custom text view. Please have to look into it [Custom font for clock textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36904466/custom-font-for-clock-textview)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can download Fonts from Google Material

1. Go to layout editor
2. Select your `view` and view `All Attributes` on your right side and find `fontFamily`

[image: fontFamily Attribute with default font]

3. Now click `down arrow`, it will open a window for selecting font

[image: Resources of Google Fonts]

4. Find your desired font, you can also search and click `ok`
5. Your `Chronometer` will look differently

[image: Preview of changed font]

Here is the code

```
<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chronometer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/allan_bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**If in case font does not change** use this in your `Activity.class`

```
Chronometer chronometer = findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

chronometer.setTypeface(ResourcesCompat.getFont(this, R.font.allan_bold));
//replace allan_bold with your desired font
```

**Edit 1**
Here is the Output in the device
[image: Device output]

Hope this will help!

Comment: Worked! But only programmatically version.

Answer (score 1):

I just follow this to add font to Android
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html

1. Copy .ttf / .otf file to "res/font" folder
2. Generate font resource file with style and weight details.
3. Set new font as `android:fontFamily="@font/sample_font"`

Check sample code below, with comparison with and without adding font

```
<!--With Font-->
<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/chronometer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/framelayout"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/sample_font"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/audio_player_chronometer"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.528" />

<!--Without Font-->
<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/audio_player_chronometer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/framelayout"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/framelayout" />

<!--sample text-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:fontFamily="@font/sample_font"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Screenshot [image]

Comment: And also check numbers that you set with font, most time numbers style  not much difference with default font.